# Sharepoint 2013 HTML editor inserting &nbsp; tags on save

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, richhtmlfield

I've got the following code in the HTML editor.
`<div><img src="image.jpg"></div>`

When I click publish a non-breaking space is added to the markup.
`<div><img src="image.jpg">&nbsp;</div>`

How can I stop SharePoint from inserting these tags?!
Help!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<div><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: I should have specified my markup, the IMG tag does have a closing "/"

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything.

Comment: Try this <img src='image.jpg'></img>

Comment: That gets changed to a single <img /> tag.

Comment: Try adding an alt to the tag

Comment: I've tried with alt tag and without, no change.

Comment: Last suggestion, try putting line breaks after tag..

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue occurs when you use an h1 tag.  SPD will add a `&nbsp;` after the opening  tag.  A workaround is to surround the text with a span tag. Try this for your issue--

```
<div><span><img src="image.jpg"></span></div>
```

With self closed image tag (XML prefers a closing tag.):

```
<div><span><img src="image.jpg"/></span></div>
```

SPD = POS editor.

Comment: This does not work either. It just adds the `&nbsp;` after the `</span>`.

Comment: Can you try in a content editor web part? I just tried and the editor replaces `<div><img src="image.jpg" /></div>` to `<div><img src="image.jpg" alt=""/></div>`. So basically it just adds the alt tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this works *most* of the time.

If you add the non-breaking space entity (`&#160;`) before Sharepoint does, then you have a little more control over where it ends up.

If you save this HTML in the Sharepoint editor:

```
<div>
  <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

it will get saved as:

```
<div>
  <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="" />&#160;
</div>
```

The only real way to make the space go away is to hide it by reducing the font size to 0 or programmatically remove them with script (ugly).

To hide the space, update the HTML in the editor to include the `&#160;` *before* Sharepoint does and it will leave it alone. Wrap your `<img>` tag in a span and set that to have no font size.

**Updated HTML for the editor:**

```
<div>
  <span class="text-zero"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="" />&#160;</span>
</div>
```

The CSS for the class `text-zero` would be:

```
.text-zero {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

If you don't add the `&#160` in your HTML in the editor, it may end up adding it *after* the closing `</span>` tag.

I can't guarantee that this will work 100% of the time, because Sharepoint puts the non-breaking space characters after some images and not others, but it has worked in a lot of instances and seems more stable than some other solutions.